# Lambda calculus in practice

Tags: functional-programming, lambda-calculus, proof, reduction

How to choose a language, a lambda term (λx.y)((λx.xxx)(λx.xxx)) actually calculated? In other words, need a language to the normal order reduction and the weak type system.

Answer (score 2):

What have you search for and what have you found so far?

I'd say there is no standard language that meets this requirement, since in most languages you always have different types, not just untyped terms. You probably need a pure lambda calculus interpreter (implementing one is a good exercise).

Comment: Oh, thank you very much! This is a simple idea - "A lambda calculus interpreter"
For example, [this](http://lci.sourceforge.net)